# Update by id but only the field i want

Tags: php, database, row

Im tryin to make my update form and query to update by id. But when i put the data in the form he updates all the fields even tho it dont have any data so in the database he get gets "0".
I need to update just the field that have data.

Can you guys help me?

**Its giving me always that i have Undefined variables! And only updates the first and second fields!**

Thanks, here´s my code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['alterar'])) {

    $id_cliente = $_POST["id_cliente"];
    $nome_cliente = $_POST["nome_cliente"];
    $telefone_cliente = $_POST["telefone_cliente"];
    $morada_cliente = $_POST["morada_cliente"];
    $email_cliente = $_POST["email_cliente"];
    $servico = $_POST["servico"];
    $n_pecas = $_POST["n_pecas"];
    $tp_arranjo = $_POST["tp_arranjo"];
    $descricao = $_POST["descricao"];

    } 

    $query = "UPDATE `clientes` SET ";
if ($nome_cliente) $columns[] = "`nome_cliente`        = '{$nome_cliente}'";
if ($telefone_cliente) $columns[] = "`telefone_cliente`= '{$telefone_cliente}'";
if ($morada_cliente) $columns[] = "`morada_cliente`  = '{$morada_cliente}'";
if ($email_cliente) $columns[] = "`email_cliente`   = '{$email_cliente}'";
if ($servico) $columns[] = "`servico`         = '{$servico}'";
if ($n_pecas) $columns[] = "`n_pecas`         = '{$n_pecas}'";
if ($tp_arranjo) $columns[] = "`tp_arranjo`      = '{$tp_arranjo}'";
if ($descricao) $columns[] = "`descricao`       = '{$descricao}'";

$columns = implode(",",$columns);
$query .= $columns . " WHERE id_cliente='$id_cliente'";


    mysql_query($query);

    ?>
```

Comment: Nice [sql injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: put `if (isset($_POST['alterar'])) {` your `DATABASE CODE` `}`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @MarcB: Very constructive comment there partner...

Comment: ok! but can someone put some explainable code for me so i can understand better?

Comment: @mjayt: after the 500 kazillionth post with blatant injection problems, you get a bit tired writing up proper comments and opt for the short-but-sweet-and-snide versions.

Comment: Or, you could just answer the posters question and let them worry about the security... just a thought :)

Comment: Marc B suffers from that problem called...arrogance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query to only list columns to be updated if you have values to update them with.  This requires building the query string dynamically based on conditions.

Example:

```
$query = "update `clientes` set ";
if ($nome_cliente) $columns[] = "`nome_cliente`= '{$nome_cliente}'";
if ($telefone_cliente) $columns[] = "`telefone_cliente`= '{$telefone_cliente}'";
//etc..

$columns = implode(",",$columns);
$query .= $columns . " where id_cliente='$id_cliente'";
```

NOTE: As others have mentioned, this is not secure! You should always sanitize user input before passing it to your database.

Comment: Its giving me always that i have Undefined variables! And only updates the first and second fields!

Comment: I showed you the principle as pseudo-code, you still have to fill in the gaps as far as proper coding.  You initially receive values from your $_POST variables and assign them to those other variables.  You must check if they exist (and sanitize them) or give them a default value of false or something, or else wrap those variables in the conditions with `isset($variable)`, etc...IOW the purpose of the answer was to answer your question, not provide php 101 lessons ;)